# Android moving back from activity issue

Tags: android

I am writing an application in which there are 5 activity A,B,C,D,E,F.Activity A is a login screen when user login A invoke a screen which has four tab and each tab has a screen.I want when user move from login screen to Activity B pressing back button should not come to login screen until not logout.

My tab activity has four screen like first one is monitoring and other are chat,operators and controls.I want pressing back button does not come to first login screen until logout how can this possible.

Actually i want until the user logout pressing back button come to monitoring screen that come after login.If user close the application using home button and then again start the application come to monitoring window not the login screen.how can this possible.

Comment: get solved problem.thanks you all.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say finish() and then go to your next Activity from loginscreen

// your click

finish();

Intent  i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class)
startActivity(i);

From your last activity say i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_NO HISTORY) and call loginscreen

Comment: I used the method as you told but using this on pressing back button activity is being finish and when i again start the activity come to login.i want if activity is finish but when i start it again it come to monitoring window not the login screen until logout.

Answer (score 0):

override this method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

....
}
```

Comment: Actually i want until the user logout pressing back button come to monitoring screen that come after login.If user close the application using home button and then again start the application come to monitoring window not the login screen.how can this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override **onKeyDown** method in other activities.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // check whether user logged out or not and react accordingly.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I hope it may help you.